# Getting "'__name__' not in globals" when updating custom plugins for 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, check-mk

I have updated my `check_mk` from 1.6.x to 2.0.x

My custom omd-plugins got messed up and so I started to refactor them for the new 2.0 API with the help of this [article](https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/devel_check_plugins.html).

However, when the time for testing came, I got this:

```
OMD[my_omd]:~$ cmk --detect-plugins=my_plugin -vI my_host.my_company.de
Error in plugin file /omd/sites/my_omd/local/share/check_mk/checks/my_plugin: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

Comment: You might want to refer to the Checkmk forum on this one, as your chances to get a good answer there are probably more likely than using this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using sym-links.

For source-control, I have a git-repo. I had put sym-links pointing from the old `checks`-directory back to the plugin-file in that repo. Starting through the above mentioned guide, I created a new sym-link from the new `local/lib/check_mk/base/plugins/agent_based/`. Adding the required `.py` suffix in the process. So now I have 2 sym-links pointing to one piece of code, which I had modified in-place.

Turns out: If you do not delete the plugin from the old location, you will always test the old plugin. With sym-links, you will test the new code in the old environment, giving you that error.

Notice the path in the error-message!

As for the `__name__` error itself: It seems to come from doing relative imports `import .something`. Notice the leading dot. It means "in the same directory as this file". Somehow the old environment was not able to cope with that.

Comment: Be very careful with symlinks in the ~/local/ structure of an omd site. There is plenty of possibilities to mess something up or get unexpected behavior. If you know what you are doing you are probably fine though.